# How to run multiple JBoss EAP 6.3 instances as Windows services

Tags: jboss, windows-services, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

We are migrating our JBoss EAP 4.3 infrastructure to EAP 6.3 (standalone). 
We currently run several instances on each machine by having different server folders:

- JBOSS_HOME\server\instance_1
- ...
- JBOSS_HOME\server\instance_n

and a different set of startup scripts for each instance:

- JBOSS_HOME\bin\run_instance_1.bat ; JBOSS_HOME\bin\service_instance_1.bat
- ...
- JBOSS_HOME\bin\run_instance_n.bat ; JBOSS_HOME\bin\service_instance_n.bat

This way you can define SERVERNAME and SERVERIP for each instance from service_instance_X.bat.

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot seem to find a similar mechanism on EAP6.3. The closest I got was this command:

```
JBOSS_HOME\bin\standalone.bat -Djboss.bind.address=%SERVERIP% -Djboss.bind.address.management=%SERVERIP% -Djboss.server.base.dir
=%JBOSS_HOME%\%INSTANCENAME%
```

which does the job, but that does not help when running it as a service.
There is one promising option to prunsrv which is ++JvmOptions, where you can pass -D and -X options to JVM at service install time, but even when the install command runs successfully with the added options, it keeps starting up using JBOSS_HOME\standalone as jboss.server.base.dir.

Should I rather have custom service.bat, standalone.bat and standalone.conf.bat scripts? Looks like the best approach, but migrating or patching might become troublesome.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I had it working with the last option I mentioned: custom service_instancename.bat, standalone_instancename.bat and standalone_instancename.conf.bat. 
But I had to edit several parts of the scripts. Definitely not ideal, but I see no other choice. If anyone came up with a better idea, please share.